# How to change description of a include_router?

Tags: fastapiusers

im trying to pass a new description to the include_router, but it doesn`t accept [description="description"].

Below you see the selfdefined working route with a custom description.

```
from fastapi import Depends
from sqlalchemy import select
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI
from app.schemas.schemas import UserRead
from app.routes.permissions import admin_route
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from app.schemas.schemas import UserCreate, UserUpdate
from app.models.users import auth_backend, fastapi_users
from app.databases.user import User, get_async_session

test = APIRouter()


test.include_router(
    fastapi_users.get_users_router(UserRead, UserUpdate),
    prefix="users",
    tags=["stuff"],
)



@test.get("users", response_model=list[UserRead], tags=["stuff"], description="description")
async def method(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    statement = select(User)
    result = await session.execute(statement)
    return result.scalars().all()
```

Is there a way to change the standard routes behavoir in fastapi-users, without altering the plugins code?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, here is a solution where i loop through the default routes and compare them with a defined array to apply the changes on the specific position in the default routes array:

```
from app.schemas.schemas import UserRead
from fastapi import APIRouter
from app.schemas import UserCreate, UserUpdate
from app.users import auth_backend, fastapi_users

app_router = APIRouter()


app_router.include_router(
    fastapi_users.get_auth_router(auth_backend),
    tags=["auth"],
    prefix="/auth/jwt",
)

app_router.include_router(
    fastapi_users.get_register_router(UserRead, UserCreate),
    prefix="/auth",
    tags=["auth"],
)

app_router.include_router(
    fastapi_users.get_users_router(UserRead, UserUpdate),
    prefix="/users",
    tags=["users"],
)


for x in ("users:patch_current_user", "users:current_user"):
    app_router.routes.remove([y for y in app_router.routes if y.name == x][0])


route_desired_content = [["auth:jwt.login", "User login to get access to to protected endpoints", "User Login"],
                         ["auth:jwt.logout", "User logout", "User Logout"],
                         ["register:register", "Registers new active users in the database", "Create new user"],
                         ["users:user", "Gets information from the database about a specific user by id", "Get user data"],
                         ["users:patch_user", "Changes all information in the database from a specific user by id", "Update user data"],
                         ["users:delete_user", "Deletes a specific user by id from the database", "Delete User"]]

for x in range(0, len(route_desired_content)):
    route_name = app_router.routes[x].name
    for z in route_desired_content:
        if route_name == z[0]:
            app_router.routes[x].description = z[1]
            app_router.routes[x].name = z[2]
```

All default routes are set in the route_desired_content array except of the two which were removed one step above.